# how to get string from a struct in C?

Tags: c, string, struct, char

I was curious if anyone has gone about doing this before.

I'm having an issue with getting a string from a struct.  What I'm trying to do is get the string from the specific struct i'm working with, then put that string into fprintf("%s", whateverstring);

```
FILE* outfile = fopen("Z:\\NH\\instructions.txt","wb");
if ((dir = opendir ("Z:\\NH\\sqltesting\\")) != NULL) {// open directory and if it exists

         while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) { //while the directory isn't null
                 printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);  //I can do THIS okay

                 fprintf("%s\n",ent->d_name); //but I can't do this

                    fclose(outfile);

                                        }

                    }   
                        closedir (dir);

                //else { 
                 //
                    //           perror (""); //print error and panic
                        //     return EXIT_FAILURE; 
                    //}
            }
```

am I taking  the wrong approach here?  I was thinking about in some way using something like `char[80] =ent.d_name;`
however obviously that doesn't work.  Is there some way I can get that string from the struct and throw it into fprintf?

Comment: heh? did you read the manual page?

Comment: Also, no information on the struct.

Comment: [`fprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) doesn't take a format string as first argument.

Comment: fprintf(outfile,"%s ", ent->d_name). You have to give fprintf the pointer to the file as the first argument

Answer (score 1):

From the man page of [`fprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf), the function declaration is:

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
```

You did not include the first argument. Here is a simple program that proves you can write the contents of a directory to a file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *outfile;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;        

    outfile = fopen("Z:\\NH\\instructions.txt","wb");
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    dir = opendir ("Z:\\NH\\sqltesting\\");
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        fclose (outfile);
        return -1;
    }

    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
    {
        fprintf (outfile, "%s\n", ent->d_name);
    }

    fclose (outfile);
    closedir (dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming

```
char dname[some_number];
```

and the structure object

```
ent //is not a pointer
```

do

```
fprintf(outfile,"%s\n",ent.d_name); // you missed the FILE* at the beginning
```

had the `ent` been a pointer, then the above statement would change to

```
fprintf(outfile,"%s\n",ent->d_name); // note the ->
```